# determine if a variable is equal to any variable in an array in php

Tags: php

Is there a way to determine if one variable is equal to the value of any of the variables in an array?
For example,

```
IF ($a == $b) {
 echo "there is a match";
}
//where $b is an array of values
//and $a is just a single value
```

Comment: Have you tried just looping over the array? Short of a built-in, that would be the straightforward way.

Comment: So basically you want to check if a array contains a certain value?

Comment: Arrays don't contain variables, they contain values.

Comment: array_intersect() Is much faster than in_array()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Sure there is.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
if (in_array($a, $b)) {
    echo "there is a match";
}
```

If the *type* of the variable `$a` needs to match the type of the value in `$b`, you should use strict comparison to ensure you don't get false positives for things like

```
in_array(0, ['abc', '', 42]) // returns true because 0 == ''
```

Do that by setting the third parameter of `in_array` to `true`.

```
in_array(0, ['abc', '', 42], true)  // returns false because 0 !== ''
```

Comment: that fixed so many issues... thanks!

Comment: I have `string(1) "2"` and `array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["node_id"]=> string(1) "2" } }`. but `if(in_array($res['floor_id'],$result))
                {
                    echo "there is a match";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "no match";
                }` gives me no match

Comment: @FaisalQayyum it looks like the string "2" is not directly in the array, but in an array inside the array. `in_array` will not look into inner arrays. For that case you can use `array_filter`, like this: https://3v4l.org/Eag87C

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?php
$people = array("Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland");

if (in_array("Glenn", $people))
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }
?>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the value exists in the array using the [in_array function](https://secure.php.net/in_array):

```
in_array('a', array('a', 'b')); // true
in_array('a', array('b', 'c')); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$b = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
$a = "single string"
if (in_array($a, $b)) {
    echo "Yes single string is in array";
}
```

Here a description from php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$a = '10';
$b = ['1', 24, '10', '20'];
if (in_array($a, $b)){
    print('find');
}
```